# Undefined en method de React

Tags: reactjs

Cuando presiono el botón "." para agregar el decimal, el display pasa de "0" a "undefined.". Es decir, lo agrega pero el 0 se transforma en undefined. No entiendo por qué.

```
  state = {
    displayValue:"0",
    operator: null,
    pendingOperation: false,
    newValue: null
  };

inputDot(){
const displayValue=this.displayValue;
  this.setState({
    displayValue: displayValue + "."
  }) 
console.log(this.displayValue)
}

<button type="button"onClick={() => this.inputDot()}>.</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás accediendo al valor de manera incorrecta, querés acceder a `this.displayValue`, esa propiedad no existe en el componente por lo que es correcto que devuelva `undefined`, a lo querés acceder es al estado del objeto, por lo que debés anteponer `state` antes de `displayValue`, la línea quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
const displayValue = this.state.displayValue;
```